# App behaves differently when installed from IOS AppStore compared to iTunes AppStore

Tags: ios7, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

We have released a subscription based app that when the user downloads it, it starts as a trial app. When they purchase a in-app subscription they get the complete app.

The problem we are having is that if a user users the AppStore app from their phone to install the app they get the full version (Every user). and I know they haven't purchased anything. But if they download the app from iTunes, and use sync to install the app from through the computer unto their phone, the app starts as a trial and the options to buy the subscriptions are there.

I was told it had to do with the itunes indexing and a new version would fix it but a new version was approved today and we're having the same issue.

Any help is appreciated it.

Rico.

**Edit:** I have tested the same version that was sent to Apple using xCode simulator, an actual device, through adHoc development and opening the ipa using iTunes and they all work correctly. Not sure what else could be happening.

This method is called on launch:

```
// check in App Subscription status
-(void)checkInAppSubscriptionStatus{
NSString *accountType = FMAccountTypeTrial;
// get receipt
NSDictionary *receipt = [[FmIAPHelper sharedInstance] getStoreReceipt:NO];
 // if receipt found
if([(NSNumber*)[receipt objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 0){
    // get exp date from receipt.
    NSString *expDateStr = [[[receipt objectForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"expires_date"];
    NSString *productIdentifier = [[[receipt objectForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"product_id"];
    // set subscription type based on product identifier
    NSString *subscriptionType = ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:FMInAppMonthSubscription])? FMSubscriptionTypeMonthly : FMSubscriptionTypeYearly;
    expDateStr = [expDateStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Etc/GMT" withString:@"GMT"];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [FM_UIViewController mysqlTimeStampFormatter];
    NSDate *expDate = [df dateFromString:expDateStr];
    // expiration date has passed.
    NSComparisonResult result = [expDate compare:[NSDate date]];
    if(result == NSOrderedDescending || result == NSOrderedSame){ // date still valid
        accountType = FMAccountTypePremium;
        // save data for latest receipt
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:subscriptionType forKey:FMSubscriptionTypeKey]; // monthly or yearly
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:receipt forKey:FMSubscriptionLastReceiptKey]; // last receipt
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:expDate forKey:FMSubscriptionExpDateKey]; // expiration date
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:accountType forKey:FMAccountTypeKey]; // premium or trial.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //save
[self displayInitialContentView:@"InitialView"];
```

}

This is the getStoreReceipt method in the FMIAPHelper

```
// get the latest receipt
// this returns an NSDictionary of the app's store receipt, status=0 for good, -1 for bad
- (NSDictionary *) getStoreReceipt:(BOOL)sandbox {
    NSArray *objects;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    BOOL gotreceipt = false;
@try {
    NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]]) {
        NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
        NSString *receiptString = [self base64forData:receiptData];
        if (receiptString != nil) {
            objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:receiptString,FMiTunesConnectSharedSecret, nil];
            keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"receipt-data",@"password", nil];
            dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
            NSError *error;
            NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

            NSString *urlSting = @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
            if (sandbox) urlSting = @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
            NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dictionary = [self getJsonDictionaryWithPostFromUrlString:urlSting andDataString:postData];
            if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] != nil) {
                if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 0) {
                    gotreceipt = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

} @catch (NSException * e) {
    gotreceipt = false;
}

if (!gotreceipt) {
    objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-1", nil];
    keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"status", nil];
    dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
}
return dictionary;
}
```

This method handles the display of trial information.

```
// account type
FMAccountType = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:FMAccountTypeKey];
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:FMSubscriptionExemptKey] isEqualToString:FMSubscriptionExempt]) FMAccountType = FMAccountTypePremium;
if(FMAccountType == nil){
    FMAccountType = FMAccountTypeTrial;
}
```

The exempt part of the code is new on this version so I know  that's not it.

Comment: Is it possible that this is just a problem with testing on _your_ devices? What happens if you ask a friend who has _never_ installed this app to do the download using the AppStore app?

Comment: Same problem. It happens on testing devices (in the provisioning profile) and new devices.

Comment: I can't image what difference the two installation methods could have but it might help if you post the relevant code that you use to determine whether the user gets the trial or full version. Maybe someone will notice a potential problem with the code.

Comment: If a device had a previous version of the app on it but it was later deleted, and a user attempted to install it on that device (the icon would be a cloud with a down arrow instead of the 'install' button) then it oculd be the device is 're-enabling' an older, cached version of that device on the phone.  Just a thought.